# from tuples of string and integer, get number closest inside the tuple to a given value

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, integer, tuples

Given a tuple inside tuple with integers, I want to find which number is the closest inside the tuple to a number I give in input:

```
Data = (('Batik Air',int(561)),('Citilink',int(620)),('Garuda Indonesia',int(1501))
Value=500
findClosest(Data,Value)
# magic
('Batik Air',561)
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `min` to find the tuple with the smallest difference:

```
>>> Data = (('Batik Air',int(561)),('Citilink',int(620)),('Garuda Indonesia',int(1501)))
>>> Value = 500
>>> min(Data, key=lambda t: abs(t[1]-Value))
('Batik Air', 561)
```

---

Additional style tips: it's more idiomatic to use lowercase letters for variable names*, and you don't need to call `int` because those values are all ints already.

```
>>> data = (('Batik Air',561),('Citilink',620),('Garuda Indonesia',1501))
>>> value = 500
>>> min(data, key=lambda t: abs(t[1]-value))
('Batik Air', 561)
```

(*with some exceptions; see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)